# What is purpose of eos flag --enable-stale-production?

Tags: nodeos, eosio-code

I am trying to setup a private eos network but when i unset flag --enable-stale-flags node does not start producing blocks
what is exactly the purpose of this flag In which cases this flag should be enabled and when disabled